# Adding new intent and entity through code in APi.ai

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai, dialogflow-es

i want to know if there is any way in which i can add/modify/delete train intents directly (for eg: through and http call)through code in API.ai so that i can automate the intent handling process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, API.AI has an SDK. Take a look [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/sdks)